# Set zoom limit in bing maps for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, zooming, limit, bing-maps

Is it possible to limit max zoom of my map ? 
I'm using SetView to fit the map for a list of pushpins; if i have only one pushpin, map is zooming to 21.
It's way to much, I would like to limit it to 15, for example.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no single property that set the maximum zoom level. However, you can use the MapZoom event handler and check against the maximum ZoomLevel - if it is off the limits, prevent from further handling.

```
private void map1_MapZoom(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.MapZoomEventArgs e)
{
    if (((Map)sender).ZoomLevel > 3)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, MapZoom event handler is not fired when SetView it's used.

Comment: I cannot find reference to this MapZoom event handler for the WPF control?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set `ZoomLevel` after `SetView` call:

```
myMap.SetView(LocationRect.CreateLocationRect(coordinates));
myMap.ZoomLevel = Math.Min(StopsMap.TargetZoomLevel, 15);
```

Please pay attention to `TargetZoomLevel` property.